# JDBC MySQL Disable Pooling

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there an Equivalent JDBC URL with this connection string?

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
Pooling=False;
```

It would be a great help.

Comment: Equivalent to what? Where does this thing come from?

Comment: I mean equivalent MySQL Connection string to JDBC Mysql Url

Comment: @AlfelBenvicGo what you said it is not kind of clear. Could you please elaborate what you want?

Comment: If what you want is to use that kind of URL with `DriverManager.getConnection()` then there is no such "pooling" option, pooling is rather implemented by 3rd parties. For instance, in Tomcat you would normally configure your connection pool in a file like context.xml

Comment: I know what you want. My question is where did the configuration you posted come from?

Comment: @EJP It looks like an ADO.NET connection string. Most ADO.NET drivers provide connection pooling by default (which to be honest can be very messy in comparison to JDBC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent JDBC URL is

```
jdbc:mysql://myServerAddress/myDatabase?username=myUsername&password=myPassword
```

etc. You don't state where you got you original configuration from, but JDBC doesn't do connection pooling by default.